# Postman not connecting to Dynamics365 API using Oauth client credentials, console app working using same details

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, postman, dynamics-365

I am trying to connect with Postman to Dynamics365 CRM REST API.
Although I obtain a token successfully without login using Grant Type client credentials I then get a 401 error when doing a sample GET to the API.
My console application is working successfully however and is not prompting the user for login (I don't want a login prompt to appear).

I have: 
1. Registered the app in Azure AD, 
2. Created the client secret
3. Created the application user in Dynamics and linked via the Application ID to App from step 1

I've done this with two different apps and two different application users and get the same result in Postman i.e. Token retrieved but 401 error on GET.

The console app below is working with the same credentials, would appreciate any input on what is missing in the Postman config

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string ResourceId = "https://myurldev.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1";
            Task<AuthenticationResult> t = GetUserOAuthToken();
            t.Wait();
            string accessToken = t.Result.AccessToken;
            Console.WriteLine("ACCESS TOKEN \n\n" + accessToken);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n Please any key to display content of the blob");

            //Console.ReadKey();

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ResourceId);
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);  // 2 minutes  
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                //Send the Get Incident request to the Web API using a GET request. 
                var response = httpClient.GetAsync("/incidents",
                        HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //Get the response content and parse it.

                    JObject body = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);


                    string title = (string)body["title"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Incident title is : {0}", title);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The request failed with a status of '{0}'",
                           response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }

            /*
            // Use the access token to create the storage credentials. 

            TokenCredential tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(accessToken);
            StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);

            // Create a block blob using those credentials 

            CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("https://placeholderURL/SalesOrder.json"), storageCredentials);
            using (var stream = blob.OpenRead())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                    }

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n Please any key to terminate the program");
            Console.ReadKey();*/
        }

        static async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetUserOAuthToken()
        {
            const string ResourceId = "https://myurldev.crm4.dynamics.com/";
            const string AuthInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/";
            const string TenantId = "XXXX-DYNAMICS_TENANT_ID-XXXXX"; // Tenant or directory ID 

            // Construct the authority string from the Azure AD OAuth endpoint and the tenant ID.  
            string authority = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, AuthInstance, TenantId);
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("XXXX_APPLICATION_ID_XXXX", "XXXXX_CLIENT_SECRET_XXXX");

            // Acquire an access token from Azure AD.  
            AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceId, cc);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

[POSTMAN TOKEN VARIABLES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWm7V.png)

[POSTMAN REQUEST AND RESPONSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCJdR.png)

I had already added the following permissions to my APP 
[image: Dynamics Permissions]

This is the response when I analyse the token in JWT.io 
[image: JWT.io Token Debug]

Comment: After you registered your app, I believe you did gave security roles to the app??  Also are you using the correct environment in which you gave access details with your access Token.

Comment: Yes I added user impersonation API Permission in AD. I also assigned a custom security role to the application user in Dynamics. The console app is connecting correctly and returning data. It is just Postman that is failing.

Comment: Please check your token in [jwt decoder](https://jwt.io/) and confirm that you have relevant permission like [this](https://imgur.com/a/UitManh)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've updated the original question with a screenshot of the permissions and the token analysis in jwt decoder (though I am not quite sure how to interpret the response).

Comment: Hi @Tony Ju, thanks for your answer and comment. The delegated user authorisations in Dynamics are not the issue I believe as the console app is able to return results with the same credentials. I am also able to hand craft a POST / GET which obtains a token and can retrieve information. I believe the issue is Postman not sending the necessary resource identifier in the Token request. Once I confirm I will update the question with the resolution. Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Dynamics CRM only support [delegated permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions) which allow the application to access Common Data Service **acting as users** in the organization. This means client credentials is not appropriate here.

[image]

However, you said that you can use client credentials in console app. You can try with below request to get the access token.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. Delegate Permissions is the only option available currently and due to the constraints of the calling application and the desire not to show a login popup it is the best option for us. I took your point about adding the resource to the body of the Token request and that worked so thanks very much for your help!